# How to get default value of Multiline text box through JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Case is I want to prompt a message (Do you want to save changes?) if multiline text box default value is updated on .aspx page before submitting the page. I am using .text() to compare with .val(). 
It works fine in firefox. .text() shows the default value in firefox but in IE7 and 8 .text() shows updated value (like .val()).

```
if ($("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").attr("value") === $("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").text())
    return(true);
return confirm('Do you wish to save these changes?');
```

Comment: What is actually happening in IE?

Comment: .text() is giving current value (not default value) in IE. And FYI my text box is Multi line box

Comment: @user144842 - Just for clarification, a "multi-line box" is a `<textarea>` vs. the normal `<input type="text">` when rendered to the client...so that's all the javascript will care about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't give you any special function to access the `defaultValue` property, so you'd have to use the DOM property directly:

```
var field= $('#<%=txt1.ClientID%>').get(0);
if (field.value!==field.defaultValue)
     return confirm('Do you wish to save these changes?');
```

(Works for normal text `<input>` as well as `<textarea>`.)

However note that the `defaultValue` is the initial value of the field in the HTML source. If the page loaded with different content in the field, typically because you have gone to the next page and then hit ‘Back’, the `defaultValue` will still be the original value and so if you click again you'll get the changed-warning again even though you haven't touched it since going ‘Back’.

Comment: You are awesome. My hat's off to you.